# Changing the nth element of a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to change the nth element of a list and return a new list.

I've thought of three rather inelegant solutions:

```
(defun set-nth1 (list n value)
  (let ((list2 (copy-seq list)))
    (setf (elt list2 n) value)
    list2))

(defun set-nth2 (list n value)
  (concatenate 'list (subseq list 0 n) (list value) (subseq list (1+ n))))

(defun set-nth3 (list n value)
  (substitute value nil list 
    :test #'(lambda (a b) (declare (ignore a b)) t)
    :start n    
    :count 1))
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Consider using `nthcdr` to reuse the tail of the original list. Also, as `subseq` always creates a new sequence, you can use the destructive `nconc` instead of `concatenate` for less consing and better performance.

Comment: As far as naming goes, I'd expect any function named SET-... to be destructive, rather than copying. I'd probably call it COPY-WITH-SHADOWED-NTH or similar. Also, with the requirement to do tail-sharing, finding a correct, descriptive, short name becomes hard.

Comment: You could have used `(constantly t)` in your third example

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
(defun set-nth4 (list n val)
  (loop for i from 0 for j in list collect (if (= i n) val j)))
```

Perhaps we should note the similarity to `substitute` and follow its convention:

```
(defun substitute-nth (val n list)
  (loop for i from 0 for j in list collect (if (= i n) val j)))
```

BTW, regarding `set-nth3`, there is a function, [constantly](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_cons_1.htm), exactly for situation like this:

```
(defun set-nth3 (list n value)
  (substitute value nil list :test (constantly t) :start n :count 1))
```

#### Edit:

Another possibility:

```
(defun set-nth5 (list n value)
  (fill (copy-seq list) value :start n :end (1+ n)))
```

Comment: Thanks for those, and for telling me about 'constantly' - I've often needed that!

Comment: Hm… So, probably LISP not that good in a performance as to get *n*'th element, we need to go through *n* values, where's in a system languages we would just add `(n * sizeof(element))` to a pointer. That's the pay for possibility to hold as an element anything of any size.

Comment: Having to "go through n values" is a consequence of the choice of linked list here as the data structure, not because of the choice of programming language.  Choose vector or array if random accesses are prevalent, and Common Lisp certainly does provide those.  (If you are reading material stating garbage likes "The only data structure in LISP is list", throw it away.  It is outdated.)

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you mean for "elegance", but what about...

```
(defun set-nth (list n val)
  (if (> n 0)
      (cons (car list)
            (set-nth (cdr list) (1- n) val))
      (cons val (cdr list))))
```

If you have problems with easily understanding recursive definitions then a slight variation of nth-2 (as suggested by Terje Norderhaug) should be more "self-evident" for you:

```
(defun set-nth-2bis (list n val)
  (nconc (subseq list 0 n)
         (cons val (nthcdr (1+ n) list))))
```

The only efficiency drawback I can see of this version is that traversal up to nth element is done three times instead of one in the recursive version (that's however not tail-recursive).

Comment: By elegant I mean the purpose of the code should be self-evident by looking at it. Only set-nth1 passes this test so far. Also, it should be efficient, so no unnecessary consing.

Comment: `set-nth-2bis` should be pretty self-evident, and minimizes consing. Readability might perhaps be slightly improved by using `cons` instead of `list` as in `(cons val (nthcdr (1+ n) list))` but that a matter of taste.

Comment: @Terje: changed from (list...) to (cons ...)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
(defun set-nth (list n value)
  (loop
    for cell on list
    for i from 0
    when (< i n) collect (car cell)
    else collect value
      and nconc (rest cell)
      and do (loop-finish)
    ))
```

On the minus side, it looks more like Algol than Lisp.  But on the plus side:

- it traverses the leading portion of the input list only once
- it does not traverse the trailing portion of the input list at all
- the output list is constructed without having to traverse it again
- the result shares the same trailing cons cells as the original list (if this is not desired, change the `nconc` to `append`)