# How can I return list with different values?

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

If I have the following list:

```
(define thelist '(0 1 0 0 7 7 7))
```

How can I write a function that returns a new list in which the value in the requested cell is replaced.

Example:

```
(set-cell thelist 2 4)
```

This would return a new list with the same values, but in cell (2) there will be the value 4 instead of 1:

```
(0 4 0 0 7 7 7)
```

Comment: In your example, the result would be `(0 4 0 0 7 7 7)`

Comment: Here is an example to replace the nth element in a list via Lisp (similar enough to scheme to get you started): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059317/changing-the-nth-element-of-a-list

Comment: Oscar, that depends on if you are using 0 as the first index, or 1. The former is often the case in programming.

Comment: what code do you have so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you *can* implement the requested functionality with lists, the natural way to solve that problem is to use a `vector`, and remember that in Scheme indexes start in 0 (that's why the second argument for `vector-set!` is a `1` and not a `2`):

```
(define thevector (vector 0 1 0 0 7 7 7))
; thevector is #(0 1 0 0 7 7 7)
(vector-set! thevector 1 4)
; thevector is #(0 4 0 0 7 7 7)
```

Now, if you *definitely* need to use a list, something like this would work:

```
(define (set-cell lst idx val)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((zero? idx) (cons val (cdr lst)))
        (else (cons (car lst)
                    (set-cell (cdr lst) (sub1 idx) val)))))
```

And you'd call it like this:

```
(define thelist '(0 1 0 0 7 7 7))
(set-cell thelist 1 4)
> (0 4 0 0 7 7 7)
```

Again, I'm using 0-based indexing, as is the convention. Also notice that `thelist` was *not* modified, instead, `set-cell` returns a new list with the modification.

Answer (score 5):

[HtDP](http://www.htdp.org/) provides a really concrete methodology for solving this kind of problem. For this problem, your job is going to be to write down the template for lists, then to stare at it until you can see what the arguments to the recursive call should be, and what the results will be.  I'm hoping that you've solved a bunch of warm-up problems on lists--compute the length of a list, count the number of 6's in the list, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Other people have mentioned the 0-based indexes convention.  I'll assume 0-based indexes, then.

The other answers you've gotten are wrong, given how you stated your problem.  I'll cite the key point in your question (my emphasis):

> This would **return a new list** with the same values, but in cell (2) there will be the value 4 instead of 1.

The answers you've been given are modifying a list in place, not returning a newly constructed list while leaving the original intact!

Here's a correct (though suboptimal) solution:

```
(define (set-list index new-value list)
  (if (= index 0)
      (cons new-value (cdr list))
      (cons (car list)
            (set-list (- index 1) new-value (cdr list))))))
```

I didn't bother to put in error checking here (e.g., if somebody passes in the empty list, or a list with too few elements relative to `index`, or a negative index).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using an auxiliary function that starts the count from 0. On each recursion, the count is incremented, and the list is shortened.

If the desired index is hit, the recursion can stop. If it gets to the end of the list without hitting the index, the original list is returned.

```
(define (set-cell ls ind val)

  (define (aux c ls)
    (cond ((null? ls) ls)
          ((= c ind) (cons val (cdr ls)))
          (else (cons (car ls) (aux (+ c 1) (cdr ls))))))

  (aux 0 ls))
```

Answer (score -1):

What a mess above!! Keep it simple: Scheme has list-set! for this.
Example:

```
(define ls (list 1 2 3 4 5))
(list-set! ls 0 "new")
(list-set! ls 3 "changed")
(list-ref ls 0)
  => "new"
ls
  => '("new" 2 3 "changed" 5)
```

However, you might want to limit assignments on lists. Vectors are faster for this since you don't need to traverse the previous elements. Use lists whenever you can't specify the length before construction or when the length is continously changed.

Comment: What Scheme interpreter are you using? `list-set!` doesn't seem to be standard in Racket (the interpreter tagged by the OP in the question)

Comment: I think Lopez's solution is the correct answer for homework problem.